# Random element from different lists

Tags: java, list, random

I want to pick a random element from three different lists. But I want to pick it with different probabilities. I want to have these probabilites:

```
50% for `list_1`
35% for `list_2`
15% for `list_3`
```

Based on user input the picked item will be removed from the list and then goes back into one of the three lists. Then a new item gets picked. The problem is, that one or two of these lists can be empty and then it should just pick an element from the lists that are not empty. And I don't want to have the same item picked twice in a row.
I tried it with generating a random number between 0 and 1 and based on the result I pick an item from one of the lists, but I always had to check if the list was empty and if so I had to call the method again. I guess there is a better way to do this. Can somebody help me?

Here is my code:

```java
Random random = new Random();
        double number = Math.random();
        if (number <= 0.5) {
            if (!list1.isEmpty()) {
                item = list1.get(random.nextInt(list1.size()));
            }
        } else if (number > 0.5 && number <= 0.85) {
            if (!list2.isEmpty()) {
                item = list2.get(random.nextInt(list2.size()));
            }
        } else if (number > 0.85 && number <= 1) {
            if (!list3.isEmpty()) {
                item = list3.get(random.nextInt(list3.size()));
            }
        }
```

But the problem  here is, that if the list which would be selected is empty, I get no item and I need to recall that method (multiple times).

Comment: you need to post a [mcve]

Comment: What does "Based on user input the picked item will be removed from the list and then goes back into one of the three lists" mean? Does that mean that you want the user to specify in which list the item must be re-inserted?

Comment: @LucaTampellini yes, it means that the user picks one of three categories and based on that, the item will be moved into the list with that category.

Comment: If one or two of the lists are allowed to go empty and the solution must then pick from a list not empty, that would seem to potentially skew the expected probability outcomes.  You would need to refine the specification to indicate what are the expected probabilities in the case of two non-empty list.  One remaining list is obvious.

Comment: @Gardener Yes I thought so, but how can I deal with that? Let's say if list 1 is emtpy I want to have 65% for list 2 and 35% for list 3? So I know I would have to redefine all cases but one example would help me already..

Comment: Create one list of lists and put inside all the lists from which you want to pick the elements randomly. Define the probability ranges based on the size of that list (if you have 3 elements you create 3 probability ranges like you have now, if you have two you create two etc.). Then at each input you borrow the list from that big list and pick the element. Before putting it back, check if it's empty and if it is, then don't put the list back into the big list. Like that, you're always sure both probabilities are well distributed and lists are always full when you fish from them

Comment: @MatteoNNZ thanks, thats an awesome idea, im gonna implement it like that! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add these 2 private static methods:

```
private static List getOrGiveAnother(final List... lists) throws NoSuchElementException {
    for (var list : lists) {
        if(!list.isEmpty()) return list;
    }
    throw new NoSuchElementException();
}

private static Object randomValueFromList(final List list, final Random randomizer) {
    return list.get(randomizer.nextInt(list.size()));
}
```

Use them like this:

```
Random random = new Random();
    double number = Math.random();
    try {
        if (number <= 0.5) {
            randomValueFromList(getOrGiveAnother(list1, list2, list3), random);
        } else if (number > 0.5 && number <= 0.85) {
            randomValueFromList(getOrGiveAnother(list2, list3, list1), random);
        } else if (number > 0.85 && number <= 1) {
            randomValueFromList(getOrGiveAnother(list3, list1, list2), random);
        }
    } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
        //if you fall here all lists were empty : do something to handle this case
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

```java
    private static List<String> list1;
    private static List<String> list2;
    private static List<String> list3;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        list1 = new ArrayList<>();
        list1.add("1");
        list1.add("2");
        list2 = new ArrayList<>();
        list2.add("3");
        list2.add("4");
        list2.add("5");
        list3 = new ArrayList<>();
        list3.add("6");
        list3.add("7");
        list3.add("8");
        list3.add("9");

        Random r = new Random();
        int p = r.nextInt(100);

        if (p < 50){ // 50%
            p = r.nextInt(list1.size());
            System.out.println("list 1 : " + list1.get(p));
            addToAnotherList(list1, p);
        }
        else if (p < 85){ // 35%
            p = r.nextInt(list2.size());
            System.out.println("list 2 : " + list2.get(p));
            addToAnotherList(list2, p);
        } else { // 15%
            p = r.nextInt(list3.size());
            System.out.println("list 3 : " + list3.get(p));
            addToAnotherList(list3, p);
        }
    }

    private static void addToAnotherList(List<String> originalList, int i) {
        if (originalList.size() != 1) {
            String toAdd = originalList.get(i);
            originalList.remove(i);
            Random r = new Random();
            int p = r.nextInt(2);
            if (p == 0) {
                list1.add(toAdd);
            } else if (p == 1) {
                list2.add(toAdd);
            } else {
                list3.add(toAdd);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: This seems to be similar to my approach, but it doesn't check if one of the lists is empty...

Comment: NotMyName i have edit and is now fixed

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).